# Run Linux dual booted (Windows) on VMware?

Tags: vmware, cinnamon

I have a dual boot Linux and Windows 10 setup on two separate disks on my laptop and I want to access my Linux OS without leaving Windows so I thought why not create a virtual machine on VMware and choose the "Use a physical disk" option and boot Linux, but I got a warning on the setup:

[image: Vmware Warning]

What I think is that it's safe to continue with this because usually GRUB is installed on top of the Windows partition so I think I'm going to be fine but am I?

Comment: Better to not dual boot at all and just have the less used OS entirely in a VM. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9iX2qSfMhE explains why dual boot can be a bad idea.

Comment: @Mioriin That video spoke all the things I've been through in my dual boot experience and I learnt so much from it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information on using a physical disk can be found here:

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_raw.html

At the bottom it notes:

> Note: You should not use a physical disk to share files between host and guest operating systems. It is not safe to make the same partition visible to both host and guest. You can cause data corruption if you do this. To share files between host and guest operating systems, use shared folders. For details, see Using Shared Folders.

Information on shared folders can be found here:

https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html